# LibreOffice writer: Make an Hyperlink that opens an ssh

Tags: macros, hyperlink, ssh, ubuntu-11.10, libreoffice

I was wondering if it's possible to create something like a hyperlink in a LibreOffice document that when called, opens a terminal *ssh-ing* to the selected "hyperlinked?" IP

The issue is that from time to time, I need to connect via ssh to remote machines. I have a LibreOffice .odt (writer) document with a list of those machines IPs'. I'd like to make it so I can click on one of the IPs and it automatically opens a gnome-terminal with an ssh connection to it. Mainly just to avoid having to open a terminal and type ssh `myusername@what.ever.ip`

I have created a macro that seems to work:

```
Sub OpenSSH(remoteIP as Integer, Optional remoteSSHPort as Integer)
If IsMissing(remoteSSHPort) then
    remoteSSHPort = 22
End if
sshCommand = "gnome-terminal --command 'ssh -Y -p " + remoteSSHPort + " myusername@" + remoteIP + "'"
Shell(sshCommand)
End Sub
```

This seems to be working for what I need. Now, I would like to go to my LibreOffice document, select one of the IPs I have listed there, and do something like "Run the 'OpenSSH' routine with the selected ip as a parameter'

I don't really need anything fancy, or having the macro sending passwords or complex things like that. I just need it to open a gnome-terminal running the ssh command.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with LibreOffice 3.4.4. And I am a total newbie to the intricate (to me) macros world.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should be possible. You just need to use the macro URL in the hyperlink.

I use the following URL in one of Libreoffice Calc's automatic tests:

```
vnd.sun.Star.script:Standard.Module1.Macro1?language=Basic&location=document
```

As much as I remember the syntax should be protocol:Package.Module.Method

I'm not sure if the rest is neccesary for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The "issue" is that I'm very newbie to LibreOffice, so I don't know how to insert a Macro in the selected text. I mean... I have the macro, and the IP I want to pass as parameter. I go to the LibreOffice document, select the IP... and I don't see anything like "insert macro", or something like that. Thank you again, though!

Comment: You can use the menu to insert a hyperlink or you can write a macro doing exactly that. You could even create a menu entry that takes the text below the cursor and pass that to your script.